# PDF download instead of embedding in webpage

Tags: pdf, iframe, embed

I am trying to embed pdf, microsoft word and powerpoint on my webpage but instead of embedding on my browser it tries downloading the file using idm or browser default downloader. I have set the browser to view the file on the page.
I have tried the following codes

```
<embed src="https://mywebsite.com/myapp/storage/videos/2020_07_21_ZHzKNlyx8qA3i9Ej2JLWH14OmxevuDCGKk7utLskBkuacn7ZAj.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="600px" />

<object data=”https://mywebsite.com/myapp/storage/videos/2020_07_21_ZHzKNlyx8qA3i9Ej2JLWH14OmxevuDCGKk7utLskBkuacn7ZAj.pdf#page=2" type=”application/pdf” width=”100%” height=”100%”>

<iframe width="100%" height="630"
                        src="docs.google.com/viewer?url=https://mywebsite.com/myapp/storage/videos/2020_07_21_ZHzKNlyx8qA3i9Ej2JLWH14OmxevuDCGKk7utLskBkuacn7ZAj.pdf&embedded=true"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

I missed https in my url. Thanks

```
<iframe width="100%" height="630"
                    src="https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=https://mywebsite.com/myapp/storage/videos/2020_07_21_ZHzKNlyx8qA3i9Ej2JLWH14OmxevuDCGKk7utLskBkuacn7ZAj.pdf&embedded=true"></iframe>
```